# catch the error message from the description

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

This is an error I received when I try to get some information from facebook in offline mode: ([error description])

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" 
UserInfo=0x13f76dd0 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x13f76860 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://graph.facebook.com/me/?
fields=name,location,gender,birthday,relationship_status&sdk=ios&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20121003&format=json&access_token=xxx, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://graph.facebook.com/me/?
fields=name,location,gender,birthday,relationship_status&sdk=ios&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20121003&format=json&access_token=xxx, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., 
NSUnderlyingError=0x13e86790 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=200}
```

I want to get this : `The Internet connection appears to be offline.`

This one also did not get what I want:

```
NSString *description = [error localizedDescription];
NSString *message = [error localizedRecoverySuggestion];
```

This error is `facebook sdk error 5`. ([error code] = 5)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSError* underlyingError = [[error userInfo] valueForkey:NSUnderlyingErrorKey];
NSString* description = [underlyingError localizedDescription];
```

Comment: I couldn't use NSUnderlyingError. It is not recognized bi xcode. but if you mean this: `message = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSUnderlyingErrorKey];` it does not work.

Comment: It should be NSUnderlyingErrorKey. Sorry about that. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It returns null.

Comment: Just investigate the error's userInfo dictionary. Print out [error userInfo], take a look what keys and values it has got. One of the values may be the original error that was wrapped into your error. This may have multiple levels. If the error's description shows the message you want, it means it is there in the user info, you can get it. Good luck.